# show content in div without wrapping

Tags: php, html, css

I need to create a filmstrip kind of div which contains images in a single line without wrapping over. As a trial I am trying to create a div in which I can have text which does not wrap over. Sadly I am unable to figure out how to do it, I am not very good with CSS... Can anyone help?

So far I have done:

```
<style>
.filmstrip
{
    background-color:silver;
    padding:20px;
    overflow-x:scroll;  
    display: inline-block; 
}
</style>

<div class='filmstrip'>
This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test 
</div>
```

I want "This is a test" to come in a single line. (Like how it is in SO). However in my page, it wraps around...

**I am now able to show text without scroll from help in comments section...Im adding original problem statement here about showing images without wrap**

I have an array of images inside `$images`. I want to show these images in single line inside div. I tried following based on comments here:

```
<style>
.filmstrip
{
    background-color:silver;
    padding:20px;
    overflow:scroll;    
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
</style>
<div class='filmstrip'>
<?php
foreach($images as $image)
{

    echo "<div><img src='".$image->thumbnail."'></div>";
}
?>
</div>
```

But this is still coming as separate lines...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sc34m94e/ like this?

Comment: @Amit: YESS!! Will that work if I have <div> with img inside it instead of text?

Comment: updated my answer with images.. hope this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the text to come in a single line, then you have to add
***white-space:nowrap;***

To see all the text in a single line you have to add ***overflow: scroll***

According to my knowledge this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cddc72t/) will help you.

**Code**

```css
.filmstrip
{
  background-color:silver;
  padding:20px;
  overflow-x:scroll;  
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 600px;
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class='filmstrip'>
  This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test This is a test 
</div>
```

If you want the images to come in a single line, simply you have to add all the img tags inside the div.

By default  is a inline element, so it will align in a same line, adding ***white-space:no-wrap***, you will get all images in a same line without break.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cddc72t/6/) for image in single line.

Comment: Thanks for that answer - I have updated my question with original problem, can you see if you can help?

Comment: @UndefinedVariable I have updated my answer for image. Hope this helps. Fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/0cddc72t/4/

Comment: @UndefinedVariable Have you check the fiddle. Is this what you want

Comment: I wanted with images, Amit has helped me with that. I have +1ed your answer, because it was helpful thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sc34m94e/1/)**

```
.filmstrip {
    width:80%;   
    border:2px solid #000;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;

}
.filmstrip img {
    margin:20px 10px 0 10px;
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
}
```

Updated **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sc34m94e/2/)** without margin:

```
.filmstrip {
    width:80%;   
     background-color:silver;
    overflow:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding:20px;

}
.filmstrip img {    
    width:140px;
    height:140px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: I will of course! it asked me to wait 5 mins before I can do that. One quick question - in your demo, there is space between the image, in mine there is none, any idea why that might be?

Comment: its becoz of margin in img.. just remove that, you can get as you expected

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

https://jsfiddle.net/0cddc72t/5/

**CSS**

```
.filmstrip
{
    background-color:silver;
    padding:20px;
    overflow-x:scroll;  
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 600px;
    overflow: scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.filmstrip > div {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Is this what you want?